# The number edges in the distance graph

Tags: co.combinatorics

> Suppose that $E\subset \mathbb{F}_q^d$, the $d$-dimensional vector
> space over a finite field with $q$ elements. Construct a graph, called
> *the distance graph of* $E$, by letting the vertices be the elements of $E$ and connect a pair of vertices corresponding to vectors $x,y\in
>  E$ by an edge if $\lVert x-y\rVert=(x_1-y_1)^2+\dots+(x_d-y_d)^2=1.$
>
> *Remark:* by $|S|$ we denote the number of elements in a finite set $S$.
>
> Suppose that $t\neq 0$ and we know that $$ |\{(x,y)\in E\times E:
>  \lVert x-y\rVert=1\}|\geq \dfrac{|E|^2}{2q},$$ or, in other words, the
> number of edges in the distance graph of $E$ is at least
> $\dfrac{|E|^2}{2q}$.

I think that the least sentence is slightly wrong and let me explain why. The edge set of distance graph of $E$ is the set $$\mathcal{E}:=\left\{\{x,y\}\in [E]^2:\lVert x-y\rVert=1\right\},$$ where $[E]^2$ is the set of 2-element subsets of $E$ and one can show that $2|\mathcal{E}|=|\mathcal{P}|,$ where $$\mathcal{P}=\{(x,y)\in E\times E:
 \lVert x-y\rVert=1\}.$$

Hence the number of edges in the distance graph of $E$ is at least $\dfrac{|E|^2}{4q}.$ Am I right?

I know that this is kind of stupid remark and question. However, this is the first math paper which I am reading and I'd like to understand concepts very well. Thanks for your attention!

**EDIT:** Below I am about to prove the fact that $|\mathcal{P}|=2|\mathcal{E}|,$ where $\mathcal{P}$ and $\mathcal{E}$ are defined above.

Consider the map $f:\mathcal{P}\to \mathcal{E}$ defined by $f:(x,y)\mapsto \{x,y\}$. This is a well defined map and it is surjective. Hence $$|\mathcal{P}|=|f^{-1}(\mathcal{E})|=|\cup_{e\in \mathcal{E}}f^{-1}(\{e\})|=\sum \limits_{e\in \mathcal{E}}|f^{-1}(\{e\})|=2|\mathcal{E}|$$
the last line follows from the fact that for each $e\in \mathcal{E}$ its preimage $f^{-1}(\{e\})$ has only two elements and for $e_1\neq e_2$ one can check that $f^{-1}(\{e_1\})\cap f^{-1}(\{e_2\})=\varnothing.$

Comment: Yes, you are correct

Comment: yes, it is correct, and the nature of the graph it is not important for this